# Why do Italian and Portuguese Marines use naval ranks?

Tags: military, italy, portugal, infantry

Arguably, [most marine infantries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranks_and_insignia_of_marine_forces) use "land ranks", i.e., the ranks used by the ground forces, e.g., 2nd Lieutenant, 1st Lieutenant, Captain, Major, Lieutenant Colonel, etc. For example,

- 's [Infantería de Marina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_Marine_Infantry) uses land [ranks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_ranks_of_Spain)
- 's [Korps Mariniers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netherlands_Marine_Corps) uses land [ranks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_ranks_of_the_Netherlands_armed_forces)
- 's [Royal Marines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Marines) uses land [ranks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Navy_officer_rank_insignia)
- 's [Морская Пехота](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Naval_Infantry) uses land [ranks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naval_ranks_and_insignia_of_Russia)
- 's [Marine Corps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Marine_Corps) uses land [ranks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Marine_Corps_rank_insignia)

However,

- The [Corpo de Fuzileiros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_Marine_Corps) (Riflemen Corps), the Marine Infantry of the [Portuguese Navy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_Navy), uses [naval ranks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_ranks_of_Portugal) and insignia.
- The [Corpo de Fuzileiros Navais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazilian_Marine_Corps) (Naval Riflemen Corps), the Marine Infantry of the [Brazilian Navy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazilian_Navy), also uses [naval ranks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_ranks_of_Brazil) and insignia, which is unsurprising, since it was formed when Rio de Janeiro was the *de facto* capital of the [Portuguese Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom_of_Portugal,_Brazil_and_the_Algarves).
- The [Brigata Marina San Marco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Marco_Marine_Brigade), the Marine Infantry (*Fuciliere di Marina*) of the [Italian Navy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_Navy), also uses [naval ranks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_Navy_ranks) and insignia.  Note that, in the  [Brigata Marina San Marco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Marco_Marine_Brigade),

  - each [battalion](https://www.difesa.it/Protocollo/AOO_Difesa/Marina/Pagine/default.aspx) is headed by a [Capitano di Corvetta](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitano_di_corvetta) rather than by a [Maggiore](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maggiore)
  - each [regiment](https://www.difesa.it/Protocollo/AOO_Difesa/Marina/Pagine/default.aspx) is headed by a [Capitano di Fregata](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitano_di_fregata) rather than by a [Tenente Colonnello](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenente_colonnello)

  and the [Brigade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Marco_Marine_Brigade) itself is headed by a [Capitano di Vascello](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitano_di_vascello) rather than by a [Colonnello](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colonnello).

Since the Napoleonic invasions, the [Portuguese Marine Infantry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_Marine_Corps) has been disbanded **twice** and the [Italian Marine Infantry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Marco_Marine_Brigade) has been disbanded once. Each time they were resuscitated, they could have adjusted to the norms used by other European navies, but, apparently, they did **not**. Is there a reason why the [Portuguese Navy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_Navy) and the [Italian Navy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_Navy) deviate from the norm?

---

**Related**

- [Why did the San Marco Marine Brigade adopt the winged lion of Venice?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/72126/17887)

Comment: I believe most "Marines" services either are part of the Navy, or used to be. The point of them is to support the Navy. Knowing that, it doesn't seem like much of a mystery.

Comment: @T.E.D. The mystery is, though part of the navy, the Spanish / Dutch / British Marines switched to land ranks, whereas the Portuguese Marines did not. Amusingly, it seems that the Russian Naval Aviation also uses land ranks.

Comment: ...and in fact it looks like Portugal is one of those countries where [the Marines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_Marine_Corps) are still part of the Navy. Even less of a mystery.

Comment: @T.E.D. That is the case almost everywhere.  Spanish / Portuguese / Dutch / British / Russian Marines are part of their countries' navies. The USMC is the notable exception, though it's under the Department of the Navy alongside the USN and the USCG (during wartime)

Comment: Armed forces often set a high value on tradition, so they probably continue to do so because 'that's how we've always done it'.

Comment: @KateBunting Indeed. However, the Portuguese Marine Infantry, arguably the 2nd oldest, was created in 1621 when the Kingdom of Portugal belonged to the Spanish Habsburgs. However, Spanish Marines use non-naval ranks.

Comment: Britain's Royal Marines were originally and primarily army regiments starting with the Duke of York and Albany Maritime Regiment of Foot in 1664, followed by others.  The Royal Marines as part of the naval establishment under the Admiralty was established in 1755.  Army organization and ranks were used all along.  Could other navy's early marines developed through similar evolutionary process?

Comment: proportionally to country / armed forces, Brazilian naval marines are small. I doubt most soldiers even know they exist. Having sailors (with no special administrative status) using land ranks would be confusing. I have seen guards/bureaucratic enlisted soldiers at an air force base thinking visiting captains-of-frigate (insignia = 3 straight lines, rank = lieut.-col.) were 3rd-sergeants (3 chevrons, but AF chevrons are quite straight ) with entertaining but embarrassing results. Thankfully, both captains I know understand what to expect from AF soldiers and did not press any changers.

Comment: @Luiz Arguably, naval riflemen are not exactly sailors.  Rather, when embarked, they discipline sailors and protect the snooty officers from the rowdy sailors. Amusingly, the Portuguese Marines were created to fight organized crime. If you have an interest in the topic, you might want to watch [this](https://youtu.be/qO3mvdeaNx4).

Comment: @T.E.D. The Dutch, UK, French and US marine corps are part of the navy.  Actually most marine corps anywhere are part of the navy. Very few are not. So it's still a mystery to me.

Comment: @Jos - The US Marine Corps is its own independent service, separate from the US Navy. Its is true that at one time it was part of the Navy, in much the same way that at one time the Air Force was part of the US Army. It is also true that it is administratively under the executive branch Department of the Navy, along with the US Coast Guard (in times of war. Otherwise, its under DHS), but the US Marines are their own separate service with their own seat on the Joint Chiefs of Staff.

Comment: @T.E.D. Correct, in The Netherlands the Marechaussee (military police) has the same status. But that is the exception, not the rule.