# Why did the San Marco Marine Brigade adopt the winged lion of Venice?

Tags: military, italy, heraldry, infantry, venice

The [San Marco Marine Brigade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Marco_Marine_Brigade) of the [Italian Navy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_Navy) adopted the [winged lion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winged_lion) of Venice — the [Leone di San Marco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion_of_Saint_Mark) — as its symbol, and the patron saint of Venice — [San Marco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_the_Evangelist) himself — as its patron saint. Why? Did the Italian Marine Infantry originate in the [Republic of Venice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_of_Venice)?

[image: patch of the San Marco Marine Brigade]

---

**Related**

- [Why do Italian and Portuguese Marines use naval ranks?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/72110/17887)

Comment: I like this question, but how is it related to the "Related" question? Other than that they are both about Marines?

Comment: @T.E.D. My rationale is that both questions pertain to the same brigade

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [Italian Navy](https://www.marina.difesa.it/EN/thefleet/specialforces/sanmarco/Pagine/sanmarcohistory.aspx):

> In 1915 the “Marine” Brigade was reformed and included an Artillery and an Infantry Regiments , both organized in three battalions, raised to five during World War I. The Naval Riflemen experienced the tragic period of the trenches contributing to the final victory. They distinguished themselves in the defense of the city of Venice, whom the Austrians attacked several times by sea and by land (for this reason the landing force’s motto is “Per mare e per terram”). **On March 17, 1919, during a solemn ceremony, the city of Venice, grateful for the heroic sacrifice of the Navy Riflemen, awarded the Regiment with its own coat of arms, the winged lion, and the name of its Patron Saint: San Marco**. Since 1919, the Naval Riflemen Corps have been called San Marco.

Bold is mine. More details from the [Italian Navy](https://www.marina.difesa.it/media-cultura/press-room/comunicati/Pagine/2019_039.aspx), in Italian:

> Il 1917 rappresentò una decisa svolta nel crescente contributo della Regia Marina nella lotta sul fronte terrestre. A protezione dell'ala a mare della 3ª Armata, sul fronte giulio, erano operativi sin dall'inizio del conflitto assetti difensivi, costituiti da batterie costiere fisse e mobili, che si aggiungevano al possente sostegno assicurato all'Armata stessa dalle artiglierie pesanti inquadrate nel 33° Raggruppamento. La difesa venne altresì incrementata con l'utilizzo e lo sfruttamento dei canali e dei corsi d'acqua interni della laguna veneta, che furono utilizzati sapientemente per rifornire il fronte lontano dalle insidie del nemico. Dall'autunno 1917, a seguito dello sfondamento di Caporetto, e della conseguente impossibilità per la 3ª Armata di farsi carico dell'intero fronte, l'ammiraglio Paolo Thaon di Revel, Capo di Stato Maggiore della Marina e Comandante in Capo delle Forze Navali Mobilitate, assunse l'onere della difesa a oltranza di Venezia. Ciò comportò la trasformazione della Serenissima e di tutta la laguna in una efficiente base, che vide l'impiego coordinato di mezzi navali, aerei e terrestri a protezione dell'ala a mare del fronte. Venne altresì costituita la Brigata Marina, unità operativa terrestre che fu impiegata nelle operazioni sul litorale veneto. 
>  Nell'ambito del dispositivo della 3ª Armata, era quindi la Regia Marina che assumeva così la difesa della città, costituendo con i marinai del Reggimento di Fucilieri di Marina, posto al comando del capitano di vascello Dentice di Frasso, una forza articolata su quattro battaglioni che presero il nome dalle località presso le quali si erano attestati per la difesa del territorio: *Grado*, *Caorle*, *Monfalcone* e *Golametto*. L'azione dei marina appartenenti alle unità attestate sul basso Piave, tra le quali la fortissima artiglieria di Marina del 33° Raggruppamento, impedì agli austriaci di avanzare verso la città di Venezia. 
>  La campagna difensiva condotta con onore dai marinai italiani prelevati da La Spezia a Messina, dalle varie unità navali, non fu mai dimenticata dalla città veneta, tanto che al termine della Guerra, la città di Venezia, riconoscente ai Fucilieri di Marina, fece l'onore di dare al reparto di Marina il nome del proprio Santo protettore nonché il proprio simbolo, il leone alato. Alla fine del 1° Conflitto Mondiale, con decreto Nr. 444 del 17 marzo 1919 Vittorio Emanuele III di Savoia decretò che: “Il Reggimento Marina... omissis... assume la denominazione di Reggimento San Marco".

---

[italy](/questions/tagged/italy) [world-war-one](/questions/tagged/world-war-one)